# Can't download free apps

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore

When I try to download a free app it keeps sending me to the settings info about my card number. Then it says that there was a billing problem with a previous purchase. And to update my payment methods . I no longer have a credit card so how do I download free apps???

Answer (score 4):

You have to set `None` as the payment type.

For more information, see the [apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534) or [discusson](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23711615#23711615).