# If Yosemite is free, why do I have to verify billing info?

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, macos

I am unable to upgrade to Yosemite because when I press the "Free" button it takes me to  a page where I must verify my billing info., then when I press done, it gives me "your payment method was declined" !!

Since it is free, why do I have to verify my billing info ?
and if my account is verified why is it saying declined, does it try to take money out of my account ?
and how then to install the new OS ?

Note: my current OS  version is 10.9.5

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114040/cant-download-free-apps?rq=1

Comment: Merely an iTunes formality! Everybody has to do it some time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verification is for your Apple ID for purchases. You can either set the payment option to `none` if you're from the US or add a credit card to it. This eases the payment option if you plan to buy apps from the store later.

But in the case of downloading Yosemite, You will not be charged for anything.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for detailed answer. However, I don't mind verification as long as I don't get charged for the update. One more thing, i don't have a "none" option. Anyhow, the download has begin now. Thanks

Comment: @Rania-Boy If the store is set to US, the payment option `none` should be available

Comment: Sadly, the "None" option is not available for brand new accounts. A credit card is required. From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905 _If you're using the iTunes Store or App Store for the first time -- 

If you're using the store for the first time with an existing Apple ID, you must provide a payment method. After you create the account, you can change your payment information to None._